# How does innodb know whether a page is leaf page or non-leaf page?

Tags: mysql, innodb, b-tree

I have been reading mysql internals for a few of weeks,and a problem puzzled

me always.We all know leaf page acts as index in a B+ tree data structure and

the real data stored on the non-leaf page.But how can i know which one is

leafpage or non-leaf page? someone plz enlight me?tks.

Comment: Check [this Stack DBA article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36815/what-are-the-differences-between-leaf-and-non-leaf-pages/36817) which discusses your problem (I think).  Non leaf pages are what occur in the middle of the B tree.  At the very bottom of the B tree, when no more traversal is possible, you hit the leaf pages.  They contain all information in the index, and possibly more than that, if you covered other columns.

Comment: thanks very much.  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a PAGE_LEVEL field in the page header. If it's zero it's a leaf page.

https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb/blob/master/c_parser.c#L657

```
int leaf_page = mach_read_from_2(page + PAGE_HEADER + PAGE_LEVEL) == 0;
```

> We all know leaf page acts as index in a B+ tree data structure and
>   the real data stored on the non-leaf page.

This sentence doesn't make sense. You can say a table is stored in an index called `PRIMARY` or (`GEN_CLUSTER_INDEX` if a unique index is used as a primary index). The PRIMARY index is a B+ tree. The key of the index is the primary key fields. In non-leaf pages the key is the key, the value - is page id of a page below. In the leaf pages the key is the key again, but the value is the rest of table fields.

A secondary index is also a B+ tree. The key of the index is secondary key fields and the value is the primary key of the records.